# Jquery automatic image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a basic jQuery image slider (code below) which slides automatically on a timer. I'd like it to loop but it's getting stuck after the last slide. I'm just starting out with jQuery so may be missing something obvious but I can't work out what's going wrong! Can anyone help please?

Here's the code...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

//INDEX IMAGES SLIDER
    $(function() {

  //configuration
  var width = 720;
  var speed = 1000;
  var pause = 3000;
  var current = 1;

  //cache DOM
  var $slider = $('#slider');
  var $slides = $slider.find('#slides');
  var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');


 setInterval(function() {
            //move image the defined width and speed to the left
     $slides.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, speed, function() {
            //count number of slides and loop back to first from last
   current++;
   if (current === $slides.length) {
    current = 1;
    $slides.css('margin-left', 0);
   }
  });   
 }, pause);
    });
});
```

```css
#slider {
 width: 720px;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#slider #slides {
 display: block;
 width: 2880px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 400px;
 width: 720px;
}

#slider .slide img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  
 <ul id="slides">
      
  <li class="slide"><img src="images/sp_1.png"></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="images/ss_1.jpg"></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="images/sd_1.jpg"></li>
  <li class="slide"><img src="images/sp_1.png"></li>
      
 </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a little mistake. $slides.length is 1 because there is only 1 div with that id. Therefore, what you really want to use is $slide.length in your if statement. Because there are that number of slides on your page. So if you change your if statement as follows it should work:

```
if (current === $slide.length) {
```

Comment: That works! I also should be able to use '.length' better in future so double thank you :)